# How can I tell when a multiplication is finished?

Tags: vhdl

I am trying to multiply two `std_logic_vector`s in VHDL, and I am struggling to find a method to determine when a multiplication operation is completed. Approaches I have tried so far:

1. Set result signal to 0 and check if either inputs is zero: if true, the result is zero, otherwise wait for result to become non-zero.
   I think this approach is very expensive and poorly scalable, so I would prefer finding a different solution
2. I was hoping that, since statements within the same process are executed sequentially, multiplying and setting a control signal to '1' right after would make it so the control signal would only ever be set to '1' when the multiplication is finished. This unfortunately is not the case, and to my understanding this is due to signal assignment not being sequential.
3. Creating a separate process with only the result in its sensitivity list, so that the process would "activate" only when the multiplication is finished, to then set a control signal to '1'. I think this does not work because the result is a `std_logic_vector`, so the process can't determine when its value is updated.

Below is the complete code of approach 2

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplier is
    Port ( input_1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0); --max input = 128 (9 bit)
           input_2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
           start   : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset   : in STD_LOGIC;
           result  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0); --max output = 128*128 = 16384 (16 bit)
           done    : out STD_LOGIC;
           clk     : in STD_LOGIC);
end multiplier;

architecture Behavioral of multiplier is

signal working : STD_LOGIC := '0';
signal temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (17 downto 0);

begin
    process (start,clk,reset)
        begin
        if(reset = '0') then
            if start = '1' then
                if rising_edge(clk) then
                    if working = '0' then
                        working <= '1';
                        temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(input_1)*unsigned(input_2));
                        result <= temp(15 downto 0); --ugly workaround for bit truncation
                        done <= '1';
                        working <= '0';
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;            
        else --reset
            result <= (others => '0');
            temp <= (others => '0');
            working <= '0';
            done <= '0';
        end if;
    end process;
    
    
end Behavioral;
```

I have also tried slightly different variations of this, and everytime I tried to get rid of the clock signal, the multiplication would not happen. Any insights as to why that is the case?

Comment: Please note that VHDL is not really a (sequential) programming language like C or ADA, it is a (parallel) description language. Both assignments to `working` are done at the same time, but the latter "wins". You need to re-read your VHDL tutorial.

Comment: unfortunately I have been given very few resources for learning, can you suggest a good place to start? Do you think that's the cause of my problems, or just a minor aside?

Comment: The multiplication is done after all combinatorial operations are done. You can calculate an estimation with the tools of your synthesizing environment. Please be aware that temperature and voltage change the time, some certain combination will give the longest value.

Comment: Well, SO is not the place for recommendations. Please use your favorite web search engine.

Comment: Is approach 1 applicable or is estimating the only way around this problem?

Comment: As you are working with clocks, your multiplication is done after one clock cycle. Then you have to check if the timing is sufficient with your tool.

Comment: @Bananenkönig I have another project on which I used approach 1, but the multiplication seems to never complete. Any ideas as to why that might be the case?

Comment: I'm afraid you did not understand, there is only one approach in my comment. The multiplication is synthesized as a (not so small) number of combinatorial operations. After all signals have settled, the multiplication is done. You need to find the "critical path" through this logic, and then sum up all propagation delays along that path. Since this is commonly not feasible by a human, you will use your computer. The result is an estimation depending on factors of which I mentioned some.

Comment: Usually you use a synchronous design with a clock, and its period shall be longer than this maximum delay. This way you will get a working design.

Comment: Many years ago there was a hype about an asynchronous computer that was meant to realize a kind of self-clocking logic. All calculations where accompanied with some kind of "ready" signal that triggered the next stage. We are still waiting to see this technology emerge. <ironic>How comes?!</ironic>

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, this multiplication should be done after one clock cycle. A code snippet follows, I haven't tested it, but it should work for you:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.numeric_std.all;

entity multiplier is
    Port ( input_1 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0); --max input = 128 (9 bit)
           input_2 : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (8 downto 0);
           start   : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset   : in STD_LOGIC;
           result  : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0); --max output = 128*128 = 16384 (16 bit)
           done    : out STD_LOGIC;
           clk     : in STD_LOGIC);
end multiplier;

architecture Behavioral of multiplier is

signal temp : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (17 downto 0);
signal MultResult, NxMultResult : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (15 downto 0);
signal MultDone, NxMultDone : STD_LOGIC;

begin

-- reg
process (clk, reset)
    begin
    if(reset = '1') then
        Result <= (others => '0');
        Done   <= '0';
    elsif (rising_edge(clk)) then
        Result <= NxResult;
        Done   <= NxDone;
    end if;
end process;

-- comb
process (input_1, input_2, start)
    begin
    
    if start = '1' then
        temp <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(input_1) * unsigned(input_2));
        NxMultResult <= temp(15 downto 0); -- truncation
        NxMultDone <= '1';
    else
        NxMultResult <= '0';
        NxMultDone <= '0';
    end if;
end process;

-- assign outputs
done   <= MultDone;
result <= MultResult;
    
    
end Behavioral;
```

Note: I would consider to use std_ulogic instead of std_logic, because normally you don't want to have a resolved type.

Comment: If it is done in one clock cycle, why should I bother with the "done" signal at all? Also what if the "start" signal is set to 1 just before the rising edge of the clock? Then it would be impossible for the multiplication to finish "on time". Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: As you normally use synchronous designs and synchronize all incomming signals to your clock, all signals change with the clock, also inputs from "outside" like a keystroke. I don't know if your code is for FPGA or for Synthesis, but on FPGA you have DSP-Blocks, which will do your multiplication. As you know your desired clock frequency, your synthesis tool tells you if these DSP-Blocks violate the timing or not. As DSP-Blocks are very fast, you have no timing trouble with them. But it is noted, that these DSP-Blocks are little available and therefore "precious".